# Websites sub-domain and redirection

Tags: apache, http, subdomain

I have a client with an existing website for whom I'm building a conference site for a one off event.

I am trying to keep the domain name as similar to the main sites' as possible but they will be on different servers.

Can anyone advice how I can achieve directing traffic to my conference website by configuring it as a subsite/subdomain of the main site?
i.e. something like `conferece.main.com` or `main.com/conference`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by configuring a Proxy

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass /conference http://conferece.main.com/
        ProxyPassReverse /conference http://conferece.main.com/
    </IfModule>
    ServerName main.com
</VirtualHost>
```